# Hand pain during hanging on the pull-up bar

Tags: pull-ups

I have recently started hanging on the bar. Doing one pull-up is yet beyond my ability.
My hand starts hurting badly after 10 seconds of hanging. I tried putting a towel on the bar to feel soft on the hands. But still at max 15 seconds and my hand really feels pained.
Are there any exercises for the hands that can strengthen them? Any other ideas or tools I can use to get the gripping strength?

Comment: Potential duplicate questions - https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/4378/what-exercises-can-i-do-to-recover-my-left-hands-grip-strength/6008#6008 and https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1141/painful-grip-on-deadlift-and-lat-pulldown/1163#1163

Comment: "start hurting badly" isn't particularly specific, where and how does it start hurting? Is it around the thumb joint? Are you using a thumbless grip? Does it hurt just below your callus line?

Answer (score 3):

You can use straps that will remove the focus from your palm to your wrist. Low cost and are helpful if you experience hand pain or if grip strength limits you. The strap wraps around the bar in the opposite direction of your hand. So if you have an over hand grip, the straps wrap under, and vice versa.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### Two Options

1. Grip-specific weightlifting exercises
2. Resistance bands

**Grip-specific weightlifting exercises**

You can use weightlifting exercises to strengthen your grip, but be sure to increase weight gradually and not ego-lift. Any of the following will help:

- [Farmer's Carry](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p5MNNosenJc)
- [Pinch Grip Carry](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZIRUI6Pr_X8)
- Vertical Dumbbell Carry
- [Sled Drag (preferably with rope handle)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k7JsvdG9sSo)
- [Towel T-bar Row](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ERx1ROl72ZY)

**Resistance Bands**

You can use different resistance bands to assist you in a pull-up bar hang. This will probably help you more than anything, since you will be doing exactly the exercise you need to get better at but with reduced bodyweight.

Apart from using bands on the pull-up bar you can also use them directly for [grip training](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=73ObTtrhLt0).

Answer (score 0):

You should try stretching your hand ligaments before you hang.

Push your fingers back, twist them around in the sockets, etc. before grabbing the bar.

You will be surprised at the results.